# Saltwater Measurement via Arduino

Tags: arduino, current, resistance, c++, conductivity

This is a strange question, but I'm trying to learn specific uses for all of the Arduino functionalities. If I were to program the Arduino to spit back the result of analog input into serial as seen below, what information would it exactly be giving me? As of this moment, it sends me seemingly arbitrary numbers that inconsistently change based on what I stick the ends of the copper wire into.

My current setup is as follows:

> I have one copper wire in an A3 pin with the other end in a solution (saltwater for example).

> Similarly, I have an additional copper wire connected to the 5V pin with its other end in the same container of the same solution above.

> I'm feeding the Arduino through a USB connection.

```
const int analogPin = A3;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode (analogPin, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
Serial.println("\n");

int analogNum = analogRead(analogPin);
Serial.println(analogNum);
delay(5000);
}
```

The end goal/purpose of this is to ultimately measure conductivity.

Comment: Are you planning on measuring conductivity via seeing a change in voltage with the ADC on the MCU?

Comment: More or less, yeah. The idea is to send a current through the saltwater and measure how conductive it is based off of resistance, then derive concentration from there. Sorry if these ideas aren't making sense, still new to this.

Comment: Watch out for bubble formation ( [electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) ) on your electrodes as this changes the surface area, thus, the resistance reading. Liquid conductivity is often done using a transformer that couples in to the water (water path is the secondary winding).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have one wire going from the analog pin to a salt water container, and another wire going from the same salt water container to 5V. My guess is that your analog pin is floating cause it doesn't have a ground reference. Putting a pull-down resistor from your analog pin to ground should fix it. I would use a low resistance (i.e. 1Kohm) so you don't mess up your ADC readings.

Comment: That's one thing I conveniently left out when trying to simplify my system as much as possible. I have this all hooked up in a breadboard among other things in the project. I wired the analog to the same row that I have a resistor leading to a GND connection. Sorry.

Comment: @sprx2 In which case, you sporadic readings may come from the resistance of the solution. As you move your wires around, you will gain more and less resistance, which will reflect on your ADC measurements. They should not change if everything is stationary.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I've secured it's placement AND have tried moving them around. Never saw much change which always confused me.

Comment: @sprx2 What's your pull-down resistor value?

Comment: Currently 200 Ohms

Comment: @sprx2 Interesting. Can you confirm you are getting around 1023 on the ADC when you connect 5V directly to the analog pin? If you aren't getting that, then something else is wronge

Comment: Yep. 1023 unchanging.

Comment: You may just need to add more salt to your solution to make it more conductive. Only thing I can think off at this point

Answer (score 1):

The arduino analogRead() function uses the ADC to measure the voltage at the selected pin.

Measuring the conductivity of a solution is similar to measuring an unknown resistance value. Just connecting a voltage source to one end and measuring the voltage at the other end won't yield any useful information. All you will be measuring is induced electrical noise (due to the long wires acting as loop antennas, and the arduino ADC not being synchronized with the power grid line frequency.)

The most accurate way to measure an unknown resistance is to use a four-wire connection, with one pair of wires used to drive a known current value through the unknown resistance, and using the other pair of wires to measure the differential voltage across the resistor. This is how professional-quality 4-wire resistance measurement DMMs do it. But building a current source is a bit more complicated than jamming a wire into an arduino. You could add an external DAC, such as a Supply Margining DAC to inject well-controlled reference currents into the test load.

There is also the "Wien Bridge" configuration, but that requires making a differential ADC measurement, which isn't very well-supported in the arduino platform. (The ATmega328 can do it, but the arduino libraries aren't targeted at making that kind of measurement..)

Another way to measure an unknown resistance (if there is a good guess as to the expected value) is to connect the unknown resistor in series with a known resistor, power the series combination from a known value voltage source, and measure the voltage across the unknown resistor. By making the unknown resistor the lower-voltage side of the resistor divider, you can then measure its voltage without requiring a differential input. This is a simple enough scheme, as long as you have a narrow range of unknown resistance values. If the reference resistor is 10kOhm, and the unknown is 10kOhm, then the voltage will be 50% of full-scale. So far so good. But if the unknown resistor is orders of magnitude different, like 100ohm, then the test voltage will be near one or the other end of the measurement range, and it becomes hard to get a precise measurement. The arduino's ADC is only 10 bits, and its full-scale voltage is 5V, so each bit represents about 0.050V (it's not even accurate enough to argue about whether to divide by 1023 steps or 1024 LSB codes). So consider a voltage measurement error of +/-0.05V or +/-0.100V, you might be able to tell if the unknown is close to the reference resistor R, versus 2R or 10R or 0.5R or 0.1R, maybe even 100R or 0.01R, but beyond that I wouldn't expect much measurement accuracy.

Comment: I appreciate this. I'll try to decipher what a constant current source would look like in my situation, but that seems viable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers and comments already posted, it sounds like maybe your circuit is okay and you just need bigger electrodes. From your description it sounds like you just have bare wires in the water right now, which will result in way too much resistance between those two wires (small contact area with the water).

Try replacing your bare wires with some metal plates that are reasonably close together, and you should get a decent reading. The plates shouldn't need to be too large; some thumbnail math tells me that two 1cm² plates, placed 1cm apart, would give you about 22Ω of resistance with regular sea water. (Resistance should go down as a function of plate area and as a function of 1/distance, so you could do some rough math to see how much resistance your old setup was getting. I'm guessing it was a whole lot.)

*Footnote: you can't actually get any meaningful readings out of saltwater with a DC measurement like this; over time you get polarization effects that ruin the reading. But if you're just doing this as a learning exercise, try it out and watch the numbers move, just don't put any stock in any readings you may get.*